# Animating card dealing

Tags: android, animation

I have looked at the Animation class and am having difficulty understanding how exactly you do things.
In my case, you have a deck of cards in the middle of the screen and I want to animate the deal by showing cards sliding across the screen to the users (who are located on the four edges of the screen).

In some cases, I need to animate the card face-up and then show it face-down in the player hand.

I really am totally lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the SurfaceView class, which has a Canvas to draw things. Creating games and animations in general is much easier with Canvas. Good luck!

Comment: I just took a look there and it seems to be a lot of work just for a short animation. It looks more like what is required for real-time games rather than stop-start games like cards. Am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe you're right, I've never used Animations in my game developing practice, always worked with Canvas, so it's just my way of doing things. Of course, there are other ways, probably the better ones too. So, keep searching and good luck.